# Odata filter syntax against cognitive search Int32Collection field, what am I missing?

Tags: search, odata, azure-cognitive-search

I have an Azure cognitive search index that contains "wi_is" field is an Int32Collection which is set to: retrievable, filterable and facetable.

I have a document that has the following values set for that field:

```
  "wi_is": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    8,
    10
  ]
```

objective: find all documents that have both 8 and 10 in the ws_is field

Results when I query using these filters:

match-->  wi_is/any(p: p eq 10)

no match-->  wi_is/any(p: p eq 8 and p eq 10)

Why does the second one fail? I can only suspect it's my syntax and second filter will always be false b/c it is trying to match both at the same time to the field value when it iterates over the collection? what am I missing?

Tried finding solution/syntax with Microsoft documentation

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion this type of request is impossible against a simple collection due to the inverted index framework.

Inside 'any', or is always allowed. **You can use 'and' only for data types that can express range checks**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-understand-collection-filters

And an expression using 'all' returns true **if the predicate is true for every element of the collection**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-collection-operators#limitations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).